# What should I do to activate ListView in class which not extends ListActivity?

Tags: android, listview

I have http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html tutorial and I want to do the same in another class.
I don't want to do this in Activity class!!!

Comment: you can't do it from a static class, we talk about classes that run on a UI thread here!

Answer (score 0):

//you need to extends the Activity

and in your onCreate() method

you need to get the ListView id

```
ListView myListview=(ListView)findViewbyId(R.id.mylist);
myListview.setAdapter(...);
```

Comment: But I don't want to do this in Activity class

Answer (score 0):

Lunch  from an **Activity** your list view after getting reference to your **listview widget** by

```
ListView myListview=(ListView)findViewbyId(R.id.mylist);
```

in your layout after that bind data to your list view using **Adapter** by calling

```
myListview.setAdapter();
```

see this [tutorial](http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/)

[image]

and this [one](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-listview-with-iconsimages-and-sharks-with-lasers/) is a custom list view with icon

[image]